Docker Secrets do not work with postgres container
I have this docker compose file
services:
  trader:
    build: .
    secrets:
      - db_name_env
      - db_password_env
      - db_user_env
      - app_env
    environment:
      APP_ENV_FILE: /run/secrets/app_env
      DB_NAME_ENV_FILE: /run/secrets/db_name_env
      DB_PASSWORD_ENV_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password_env
      DB_USER_ENV_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user_env
      RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT: DEV
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:16.4
    secrets:
      - db_password_env
      - db_name_env
      - db_user_env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user_env
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password_env
      POSTGRES_DB_FILE: /run/secrets/db_name_env
      #POSTGRES_USER: usr
      #POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pswd
      #POSTGRES_DB: off
    expose:
      - "5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
secrets:
  app_env:
    file: ./.app.env
  db_password_env:
    file: ./.db.password.env
  db_name_env:
    file: ./.db.name.env
  db_user_env: 
    file: ./.db.user.env
volumes:
  db-data:

Whenever I use secrets in order to connect to database from app, Im receiving error about password:
failed to connect to `user=postgres database=postgres`:
2024-08-30 19:15:39             172.18.0.2:5432 (db): tls error: server refused TLS connection
2024-08-30 19:15:39             172.18.0.2:5432 (db): failed SASL auth: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (SQLSTATE 28P01)

Also I'm unable to connect using shell inside postgres container with psql.
When I do not set POSTGRES_USER_FILE env, I'm still receiving error mentioned upper, but I can connect using shell inside postgres container with psql. From this point I can create needed role and password but its cumbersome.
When I set up environment variables directly, everything is working as intended.
Appreciate any help, thanks.

What are the contents of the secret files? E.g., what does db_password_env look like?

db_name_env
POSTGRES_DB=random
db_password_env
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somerandom
db_user_env
POSTGRES_USER=random

Those look incorrect. The value contained in e.g. POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE should be the password, not a VAR=VALUE variable assignment.

You are right, thanks a lot, everything is now working as intended
